# Grouping XSLT Element based on a attribute value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement to transform the student records uniquely.

**Sample IP:**

```
<Root>
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <qty>1</qty>
            <item id="1"></stud>
        </C>
        <C>
            <qty>2</qty>
            <item id="1"></stud>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

O/P Needed:

```
<Root>
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <qty>3</qty>
            <item id="1"></stud>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

How do I do this in xslt 1.0? I tried Muenchian grouping! But failed. pls guide me!

Comment: You forgot to show the XSLT 1.0 stylesheet that you already have but that failed at Muenchian grouping.

Comment: Then you are mistaken about the "level" of questions on SO I'm afraid.

Comment: Deleting your comments does not help getting an answer. Showing your code would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a key `<xsl:key name="c-by-id" match"B/C" use="item/@id"/>`, then use that to suppress copying the items that are duplicates with

```
<xsl:template match="B/C[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('c-by-id', item/@id)[1]))]"></xsl:template>
```

and to compute the sum with

```
<xsl:template match="B/C/qty">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('c-by-id', ../item/@id)/qty)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Together with the identity transformation template you have the full stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">


    <xsl:key name="c-by-id" match="B/C" use="item/@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="B/C[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('c-by-id', item/@id)[1]))]"></xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="B/C/qty">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('c-by-id', ../item/@id)/qty)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

online as http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQs.